# What is the damage type of bleed damage?

Tags: damage, pathfinder-2e, damage-resistance

Bleed Damage (CRB p452)

> Weaknesses and resistances to *physical* damage apply.

So if I have 1d4 *bleed damage*, and cast Stoneskin on myself, the bleeding stops. But there are 3 subcategories of physical damage; bludgeoning, piercing, slashing.

If I received my bleed damage as part of an attack with a piercing weapon, would [Barkskin](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=20) reduce the amout?

> The target gains resistance 2 to bludgeoning and piercing damage and weakness 3 to fire

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Bleed is physical damage, with no further type

Without any further clarification, bleed is *not* piercing, slashing, nor bludgeoning. There are creatures and effects that grant reduction to "physical" (or simply *all*) damage; only those effects reduce bleed as well.

Notably, in the [Determine the Damage Type](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=340) general rules section, Bleed is listed separately from the other physical damage and is called "Another special type of physical damage".