# Does having resistance to bludgeoning, piercing and slashing give resistance to physical?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, damage-resistance

Is *physical* resistance a sum of its parts, or a different category? There are 3 subcategories of physical damage; bludgeoning, piercing, slashing.

If I have [Barkskin](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=20) going (resistance 2 to bludgeoning and piercing) and have [Armor Specialization](https://2e.aonprd.com/ArmorGroups.aspx) while wearing a +1 Leather armor (resistance 2 to bludgeoning), do I count as having resistance 2 to physical (for example against [bleeding](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/202156/49393))?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## No, Physical Resistance is its own thing

As per the example of bleeding, physical resistance is required for resisting pure physical damage with no further typing. No other type of resistance, you wouldn't expect to get an extra resistance for 3 types of elemental damage, would you?

In the rules for [Damage Types](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=335), Physical is noted as a main type of damage and then that the main types *of* physical are bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing. As a note bleeding, a type of physical, is even a main damage type:

> Damage dealt by weapons, many physical hazards, and a handful of spells is collectively called physical damage. **The main types of physical damage are bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing.**

> **Bleed Damage**
>
> Another special type of physical damage is bleed damage.

An example of a source of physical resistance is [Invincible Mutagen](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=114), where it *specifically* states that you gain resistance to physical:

> The fortifying additives you brew into your mutagens make your juggernaut form impervious. Whenever you’re affected by a juggernaut mutagen, **you gain resistance to all physical damage equal** to your Intelligence modifier (minimum 0).

Comment: Examples of damage resistance of typed physical damage that isn't the pierce/bludgeon/slash (eg. bleed) could improve the answer, but i'm meant to be working so i'll have to search for those later

Comment: I think you are right, "Another special type of physical damage is bleed damage" is the key sentence, I would remove the other points