# How can I get resistance to physical?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, damage-resistance

I'd like to get resistance to Physical. Getting just resistance to bludgeoning, piercing and slashing [does not work](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/202182/49393), but [Stoneskin](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=312) does.

What else can give me resistance to physical damage?

Comment: Would resistance to all damage also be on the table?

Comment: @ESCE, yes, of course

Comment: Are you trying to resist Bleed damage specifically (based on the logical progression of questions I've seen here) or is there another reason you want Resist Physical?

Comment: @Ifusaso, not just Bleed, the other subtypes of physical are also very common, so worth resisting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Be a [Cosmos Oracle](https://2e.aonprd.com/Mysteries.aspx?ID=4)

They get resistance to physical equal to (2+half level).

Progressing their curse literally makes them a pushover, but most monsters do not grab or trip. You should be quite safe in the back row, however, you won't be able to use Spray of Stars from there.